# GIT: "missing necessary objects" and "remote: error: refs/pull/904/head does not point to a valid object!"

Tags: git, github

I currently have a repository that I've been working for a few days, however. I seem to be unable to push anything to it anymore. We deforked our repo because it was getting to busy and the original repo kept getting a ton of PRs, the owner allowed us to defork the repo in that case.

However, whenever I or someone tries to push we get this error:

```js
... 75 more lines ...
remote: error: refs/pull/979/head does not point to a valid object!
remote: error: refs/pull/980/head does not point to a valid object!
remote: error: refs/pull/980/merge does not point to a valid object!
remote: error: refs/pull/984/head does not point to a valid object!
To https://github.com/placeAtlas/atlas.git
 ! [remote rejected] cleanup -> cleanup (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/placeAtlas/atlas.git'
```

This happens to us, but also to forks. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hum, it looks like deforking the repo broke references GitHub had on old pull requests. Do you get this error pushing to your repo or the original one?

Comment: In any case, that seems like it might need a service call to GitHub themselves...

Comment: When pushing to the main repo this happens, I've also heard complaints from people with a fork when pushing from their computer. 

The repo itself does not have this problem, so changing files from the website works without a problem.

Comment: I currently am in the pain of being stuck in the support system of github, being unable to push anything,

Comment: GitHub normally never delete *any* commit to avoid problems like this, but apparently something went wrong. This is not a Git issue but rather a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted github support, they yeeted the problematic tags/pr's and I was able to use my repo again!

#### My best guess is that it was an issue with:

- I forked my repo initially on my personal account
- That repo became VERY popular
- I moved it to a org
- It became even more popular
- We got permission to detach as per the license and call the project our own
- The repo was detached from the origin
- Git broke.exe